# Can you keep your container running while staying attached to debugging in PyCharm

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I have seen this for example with web applications. However I don't seem to get it.

In PyCharm I've setup my interpreter to be docker. If I run a python file now, it wil go trough the container. But when the script is finished it quits the container and shuts it down.

[image]

What I want to to is start the container once. Then edit code. Run the code in the container. Then check inside the container if the right files are created etc. And I want the ability to use the debugger.

I've seen setups were they attached the /app folder to the running container. But I don't seem to understand how to set it up.

How do you set this up in PyCharm?

Comment: The container is just a wrapper around a Python interpreter.  Without Docker, does PyCharm have the ability to start a single long-running Python interpreter and update code in it?  What value is there in keeping the container running?

Comment: Because then you can attach from a terminal and check your file system. For example your code generates a CSV. And you want to check if it is done right. Of course I could attach the output directory and look on the host. But I want to check behavior inside the container, change code, run again and then check the container again. Is this possible?